# Brand new project with no code other than App.js: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When trying to use the `CountdownCircleTimer` from `react-countdown-circle-timer`, I get the following errors in my browser:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I only have the following code, absolutely nothing else, no other components in my React project:

```
import './App.css';
import { CountdownCircleTimer } from "react-countdown-circle-timer";


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Timer/>
      <CountdownCircleTimer
        isPlaying
        duration={10}
        colors={[
          ["#004777", 0.33],
          ["#F7B801", 0.33],
          ["#A30000", 0.33],
        ]}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is what my `package.json` looks like:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-countdown-circle-timer": "^2.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  }
```

Here is my `index.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I am at a loss as to why this is happening. What can I do to fix it? This is a brand new React project and I wanted to test this component inside `App.js` before moving forward.

Thank you.

Comment: You are misusing a hook in another component. Maybe `<Timer/>`

Comment: I removed this file actually, and I still get this error. This was an empty component before this.

Comment: Try removing `<CountdownCircleTimer>`. The problem could be coming from a library(package)

Comment: I need this component, unfortunately. I was not able to find another component similar to it, but I suspect you are right

Comment: The code you've shared [works as-is](https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-frost-on8kv?file=/src/App.js). Please share a [mcve], including which versions of React and the countdown plugin you're using.

Comment: How are you using the `App` component?

Comment: Hello, I updated the thread by adding the package.json file. Also I'm  the one who opened the issue on github; but after seeing you linked to this SO thread, I have now closed it since the issue seems to be on my end rather than in the code. Thank you for your prompt response.

Comment: It looks like you're using the same versions as the code sandbox, so the problem might be how the `App` component is used.

Comment: I have deleted the project and created a new one. I am not sure what the problem was earlier, but it might be that I forgot to do `npm install` before starting the project. My apologies for this, I am still new and I am learning, so I make small but frustrating mistakes like this. Thank you for taking the time to help me. EDIT: actually `npm install` was not the issue. I genuinely have no idea what the problem was.